Is there any way to have multer fail gracefully if a file is not in the request body?
I want to be able to capture when a file is not included in the request body and report it back in the response, but multer always bombs with the exception: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE
Is there any way to capture this?
express-validator doesn't appear to be able to validate files.

If the file is missing, you can simply check if there is file in req.file.
if(!req.file) return res.status(400).json({error : "File must be provided"})

But to catch error you mention, you need to call Multer middleware manually/from the controller, and catch Multer errors, and then you can detect specific erorr, such as LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE, and respond accordingly, for example:
if(err.code === 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE') return res.status(400).json({error : "File upload not valid"});

Modified error handling example from the docs
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
        if(err.code === 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE') return res.status(400).json({error : "File upload not valid"})
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    }

    // Everything went fine.

    // now check if file is provided
    if(!req.file) return res.status(400).json({error : "File must be provided"})
  })

})

